# Named Entity Recognition (Ner) - Organization Name Database

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm Working on my current graduating project which is Named Entity Recognition For Turkish. The recognizer should catch Turkish words when i work with Person Names and Locations (Sometimes locations can be in different Languages, for example Hilton Hotels in Taksim/Istanbul) all i need add "Hotel" in my dataset which is Full of specific location tags like Hotel , Restaurant or Mall. But when its come to Organization Name Tag. I need to find a good dataset of bands , products , company names, But cant figure out how to find or collect this dataset

In stanford nlp tool : http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process

When i type Facebook , Nike , Adidas etc it can find it's organization. So is there any way to have that organization name Dataset ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in a data resource with these organizations names. You can use one of the knowledge bases KBs available such as

- [DBpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess)
- [YAGO](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/)
- [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/guide) It cannot be downloaded only online access.
- [FreeBase](https://www.freebase.com/)

All of them have names of these organizations and more, you will need some effort to extract the organizations only using their types. For example, **YAGO** has downloadable file with possible entities and their types. You can filter it on  and then you can use hasMeaning data to get all possible names.

Yago and BabelNet have been used to NER or Named Entity Disambiguation system AIDA and Babelfy.

[AIDA](https://github.com/yago-naga/aida) offers a robust dataset of possible Entity Names, that can be used for NER.

Comment: Dear Mohammed thanks for your reply, Its very helpful. Im gonna use yago because it has a nice set and i can manage them easliy. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome... If you are going to use Yago .. check these set of possible names .. it makes it more powerful for  your task.

Answer (score 1):

try collecting them from wikipedia. Its a massive source.
You can write a parser that collects the information of specific types of entities from wiki dumps. Wikipedia has a hierarchical structure of categorizing people, locations and organizations.

Comment: Thank you for reply but Turkish organization in wikipedia(vikipedi) is very small. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_of_Turkey .Also i dont know how to parse them and collect only names and if it wont interrupt your work i really want to know how. You can give me hints. thank you again

Comment: if you look at the dump, its a massive xml file. Each page is a xml tag in particular schema. If you read the first 2 lines of text in each xml page level node it usually says like: XYZ is an organization doing ABC or some text which you can easily interpret. If you have to build an organization list, you can also look at the english dump too.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: If you think that this answered you question, could you kindly mark it as an answer.